# Why does the cin extraction operator cause a segfault?

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    char * c;
    cin >> c;
    return 0;
}
```

I'm trying to get a C string line from the user whose length is not known. I know that if I declared `c` as `char c[80]` instead of `char * c` then it wouldn't cause a segfault.

However what if I didn't want to restrict the user to `80 - 1` characters? I could use a really big number but that would just waste space.

I would also really like to know why the above program causes a segfault. From what I understand the `cin` extraction operator (`>>`) knows to `NULL` terminate a C string. What exactly is causing the problem?

Comment: Now that you know that you haven't allocated the memory, use strings instead of char* when you write c++

Comment: You've allocated no space for the string to occupy. Instead of trying to allocate space directly, you probably want to use `std::string`: `std::string c; cin >> c;`, which will automatically resize itself to hold the data that's entered.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The program segfaults because the pointer `c` is not initialized. You need to allocate memory for the buffer before reading the data into it:

```
char * c = new char[80];
cin >> c;
cout << c << endl;
delete[] c; // Now you need to delete the memory that you have allocated.
```

To avoid restricting your input to `N` characters, use strings. They resize dynamically as you need:

```
string c;
cin >> c;
cout << c;
// You do not need to manage string's memory - it is done automatically
```

Answer (score 2):

You've allocated no space at all for the string when you use only `char *c;`. The variable declaration creates a pointer to `char` which is uninitialized. Then you use `cin` to read a string into that space. `c` could point to *anything*, and in any case will point to memory that doesn't belong to you.

You'll need to allocate space for the string before you try to fill it from `cin`.

If you don't want to assume a limit on the string length, you can loop and `realloc` more space until the input is completely read, but as has been mentioned, if you use `std::string` instead of C strings, then this will be handled for you.

Answer (score 0):

That is because you did not allocate memory for your string.